# Spring Batch: How retrieve the skipped exceptions for Testing purposes

Tags: spring-batch

I am working with `Spring Batch` *3.0.7.RELEASE* version

About **Skip** I have the following:

```
<batch:chunk reader="personErrorSkipFileItemReader"
             processor="personErrorSkipItemProcessor"
             writer="personErrorSkipFileItemWriter"
             commit-interval="100" 
             skip-limit="11">
        <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
            <batch:include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException"/>                                           
        <batch:include class="com.manuel.jordan.batch.exception.PersonBatchException"/>  
        </batch:skippable-exception-classes>         
</batch:chunk>
```

It works how is expected.

For **logging** and **test** purposes I need retrieve the following data:

- skipped elements (for example 8 of 11) showing the amount such as:
- By `FlatFileParseException` 5
- By `PersonBatchException` 3

Even better if can show in what step and area (reader, processor, writer) was thrown each skipped item.

Working through [JobExecution](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecution.html), I have the following

```
List<Throwable> exceptions = jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions();
logger.info("exceptions size: {}", exceptions.size());
for(Throwable throwable : exceptions){
    logger.error("Throwable Class: {}", throwable.getClass().getSimpleName());
    logger.error("{}", throwable.getMessage());
}
List<Throwable> exceptions_ = jobExecution.getFailureExceptions();
logger.info("exceptions_ size: {}", exceptions_.size());
for(Throwable throwable : exceptions_){
    logger.error("Throwable Class: {}", throwable.getClass().getSimpleName());
    logger.error("{}", throwable.getMessage());
}
```

But the size of both collections are higher than 1 and show the exceptions just when the Job completes how `FAILED`.

Because 8 < 11, the `Job` completes how `COMPLETED` and the lists sizes returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

implement SkipListener , It has three callback methods

1 :onSkipInProcess
2 :onSkipInWrite
3: onSkipInRead

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/SkipListener.html

Comment: It works only for runtime purposes, that methods return `void`. I need retrieve that data for `@Test` purposes, for `assertEquals` evaluations.

Comment: you are testing individual step /tasklet of batch ?

Comment: I want for a Step and all the Step. Thus both scenarios.